# Dynamically parse text from cell in worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am writing a small excel VBA/Formula sheet for a coworker of mine.
The department is going to host a 'weight loss challenge' for associates.

I have a vba code to pull the e-mail information looking for these fields

```
`ColumnA = Subject Line
ColumnB = Date of e-mail
ColumnC = Sender
ColumnD = Text of e-mail body`
```

I am struggling to parse/extract certain text from the body of the e-mail.
Associates were instructed to fill out their email in this format:

```
`Associate Name: Test McTesterson
Associate E-mail: Tmctesterson@gmail.com
AIN: 123456
Weight: 200`
```

I have mostly been able to get everything except for the WEIGHT.. This is because there is no 'identifier' after the weight to do a "MID" search, and using RIGHT returns everything including e-mail signatures and tags.

Is there a way to search/find Weight: and then get only the first 5-7 characters including spaces?

Code to search e-mails and pull them into excel.

```
`Dim OutlookApp As Outlook.Application
Dim OutlookNamespace As Namespace
Dim Folder As MAPIFolder
Dim OutlookMail As Variant
Dim i As Integer`
`Set OutlookApp = New Outlook.Application
Set OutlookNamespace = OutlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set Folder = 
OutlookNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("inital weigh 
in")`
`i = 1`
`For Each OutlookMail In Folder.Items
If OutlookMail.ReceivedTime >= Range("From_date").Value Then
Range("eMail_subject").Offset(i, 0).Value = OutlookMail.Subject
Range("eMail_date").Offset(i, 0).Value = OutlookMail.ReceivedTime
Range("eMail_sender").Offset(i, 0).Value = OutlookMail.SenderName
Range("eMail_text").Offset(i, 0).Value = OutlookMail.Body`
`i = i + 1
End If
Next OutlookMail`
`Set Folder = Nothing
Set OutlookNamespace = Nothing
Set OutlookApp = Nothing`
```

This brings e-mails over like this:

```
`subject    = Initial Weigh In
date = 8/12/2019 9:59   
sender = Test McTesterson
text = "Associate Name: Test McTesterson`
`Associate E-mail: Tmctesterson@gmail.com
AIN: 12345
Weight: 221 
Test McTesterson
Director | Clinical Process Transformation
“Everything should be made as simple as possible, but not one bit 
simpler.” – Albert Einstein`
```

I am using formulas to parse the text. 
To get the associate name I use
     `= MID(D2,SEARCH("Associate Name:",D2)+16, SEARCH("Associate E-mail:", 
    D2)-SEARCH("Associate Name:", D2)-16)`
THIS WORKS AS EXPECTED

to get the associates e-mail I use
    `=MID(D2,SEARCH("Associate E-mail:",D2)+17,SEARCH("AIN:",D2)- 
    SEARCH("Associate Name:",D2)-50)` 
THIS WORKS BUT WITH SOME ADDITIONAL CHARACTERS OCCASIONALLY

To get the AIN I use 
    `=MID(D2,SEARCH("AIN:",D2)+4, SEARCH("Weight:", D2)-SEARCH("AIN:", D2)-4)` 
THIS MOSTLY WORKS CORRECTLY

To get the Weight I am trying to use
    `=RIGHT(D2, SEARCH("weight:",D2)+1)` 
THIS IS NOT WORKING

Is this the best way to parse text like this?  and if so.. is there a way for me to get the Weight: without grabbing the senders signature and e-mail tags?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you can search for `Weight:` (or `LCase("weight")`, which would be better) to find the start, and find out what the end-line character is, and take everything between. It is likely to be `CHR(13)` or `CHR(13) & CHR(10)` or something similar. Perhaps something like this?

```
Dim Body As String, Start As Integer, LineEnd as Integer
Body = OutlookMail.Body 'This is just to shorten the name
Start = InStr(LCase(Body), "weight:") + 7
LineEnd = InStr(Start, Body, vbNewLine)
Weight = Mid(Body, Start, LineEnd - Start)
```

If you want it as a formula instead of having the macro parse it for you, you can make a complicated formula using `SEARCH` instead of `InStr` and `MID`, but the formula will be pretty long unless you use cells in hidden columns to store sub-formulas. As it is, a formula would be something like this:

In the Weight column:

```
MID(D2,SEARCH("Weight:",D2)+7,SEARCH(CHAR(13)&CHAR(10),D2,SEARCH("Weight:",D2)+7)-SEARCH("Weight:",D2)+7)
```

Comment: Can you tell me what CHR(13) adn CHR(10) represents?  the formula you posted doesn't work 100% but I don't know how to trouble shoot it because I don't understand what the 2 CHR() values represent.

Comment: An example of it not working 100% correctly is this: One e-mail has the weight listed as Weight: 149.2  The result of the formula (used as  =MID(D95,SEARCH("Weight:",D95)+7,SEARCH(CHAR(13),D95,SEARCH("Weight:",D95)+7)-SEARCH("Weight:",D95)+2)) created a value of 157T

Comment: Changing from Char(13) to Char(10) (still not sure what this does) seems to have fixed the issue I was having.

Comment: The CHAR(13) means a carriage return, and CHAR(10) means line feed. Many programs use both together to mark the end of a line, so you would use `CHAR(13)&CHAR(10)` to represent the end of a line.But this varies, and it could take some experimentation to find out what your output is using for the end of a line.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  That helps me understand why the change from Char(13) to Char(10) made a difference.  I'll have to remember this for potential future use.

Not sure if it matters/is consistent.. but the app is Outlook mail being copied to excel (obviously from my first question) however there is a template from an original e-mail that associate are supposed to copy/paste into their responses.. not sure if this would have made a difference?

Either way.. Thank you!